# WP custom field contains 50 names separated by comma: how to just list the first 5?

Tags: php, wordpress

As stated in the title, in my blog, I own a custom field that - for each post - contains 50 names, but it's way too much, so I'd like to just echo the first 5 names.

I'm trying with this, but it's not working properly...Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php
  $players = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Names_List', true);
  $i = 1;
  foreach($players as $player) {
    if ($i < 6) {
      echo $player;
    }
    $i++;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate through a string. This means that when you access `$players[2]` you will get the third character in the string `$players`.

You will need to convert the string into an array by using the [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function which will break the string into an array based on a character you tell it.

```php
$string = 'This is a string, This is a string 2';
$array = explode(',', $string);
```

This will break the string into parts based on a comma, resulting in array as follows:

```php
[ 'This is a string', 'This is a string 2' ]
```

Once you have turned your string into an array, you can then loop through the first 5 by using a `for` loop and setting it up to only run 5 times.

```php
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { ... }
```

This will run the code between the brackets 5 times as we are saying:

Starting `$i` at 0, whilst `$i` is less than 5 - Run the code.
After running the code, `$i++` will add 1 to `$i` and test the condition again.

The following code should be able to replace the code from the question and give you the results you want.

```php
$players = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Names_List', true);
$players_array = explode(',', $players);

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {

  echo $players_array[$i];

  if($i < 4) {

    echo ',';

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is currently just showing the first 5 digits of the first name. Weird.
Example, list is: Michael Coleman, Susan Grey, Max Steel etc... it will just list 'Micha'

Comment: It's showing the first five characters because when you access a string with a numeric id, it will return the character at that position.
For instance `$string = "ABCDEF";` `echo $string[2];` would print `C`

Comment: Is there a way to make it work considering whatever digits are contained within a comma, as a name, rather than just take characters like now? :)

Comment: Please read my answer, I explained that you can split the string into an array using the `explode` function

Comment: Sorry I read it. I'm trying to figure it out what you mean but it still just provides one letter now. Tried $string = "$players"; echo $string[5] and it echoes just the 5th letter of the word 'string' which is 'n' ... I haven't probably understood your hint, I apologize but I started working on this stuff just recently, so I'm not very used to this type of language.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you should be able to replace your code from your answer with this and get the results you're looking for. You need to have an array of player names, so that you can then access them by a numeric identifier.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. It does work perfectly now. The only lil issue was that names were shown non-separated by comma, so I added { echo ',', $players_array[$i];} but it starts with a comma before the first name listed; so I tried this { echo $players_array[$i],',';} which removes the initial comma, but now keeps one additional comma at the end of the last of those 5 names listed, lol ... well I'd say it's ok anyway... Thanks a lot man, you helped me tremendously!

Comment: Yep, so the `explode` function does remove the character used to split the string up. You could add an `if` statement within the loop to check that it's not the 5th time and add the comma. Updated my answer

Comment: It is just perfect now. Thank you so much you solved my issue in the very best way^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get first 5 elements.

Obviously you need to split the string by the comma delimiter with [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) first

```
$players = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Names_List', true);
$players_array = explode(',', $players);

$first_five = array_slice($players_array, 0, 5);
foreach($first_five as $player)
{
    echo $player;
}
```

Comment: Ottimo grazie funziona perfettamente anche col tuo metodo che sinceramente preferisco perché l'array_slice è più comprensibile rispetto a quei $i e $i++ che non avevo mai visto prima :))

Comment: Thanks, set my answer as closed ;)